# How can I use foreach function for parallel coding?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, glmnet

Following the textbook by Jared Lander "R for Everyone" (Chapter 19), I have been trying to use Elastic Net.
The textbook uses the following "foreach" code to find the optimal parameter value using parallel coding.
However, even if I write and run exactly the same code, the resulting object "acsDouble" is not a list with 11 instances of cv.glmnet objects as it should be. Instead, it is a blank list.

I have checked the textbook codes and also cleared the environment before running but the problem is not fixed.
What seems to be the problem here?

```
acs <- read.table("http://jaredlander.com/data/acs_ny.csv", sep=",",
                  header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
require(useful)
# make a binary Income variable for building a logistic regression
acs$Income <- with(acs, FamilyIncome >= 150000)
# build predictor matrix
# do not include the intercept as glmnet will add that automatically
acsX <- build.x(Income ~ NumBedrooms + NumChildren + NumPeople +
                  NumRooms + NumUnits + NumVehicles + NumWorkers +
                  OwnRent + YearBuilt + ElectricBill + FoodStamp +
                  HeatingFuel + Insurance + Language - 1,
                data=acs, contrasts = FALSE)
# build response predictor
acsY <- build.y(Income ~ NumBedrooms + NumChildren + NumPeople +
                  NumRooms + NumUnits + NumVehicles + NumWorkers +
                  OwnRent + YearBuilt + ElectricBill + FoodStamp +
                  HeatingFuel + Insurance + Language - 1, data=acs)
require(glmnet)
require(parallel)
require(doParallel)
# set the seed for repeatability of random results
set.seed(2834673)
# create folds, we want observations to be in the same fold each time
# it is run
theFolds <- sample(rep(x = 1:5, length.out = nrow(acsX)))
# make sequence of alpha values
alphas <- seq(from = 0.5, to = 1, by = 0.05)
# set the seed for the repeatbility of random results
set.seed(5127151)
# start a cluster with two workers
cl <- makeCluster(2)
# regiser the workers
registerDoParallel(cl)
# keep track of timing
before <- Sys.time()
# build foreach loop to run in parallel
## several arguments
acsDouble <- foreach(i=1:length(alphas), .errorhandling = "remove",
                     .inorder = FALSE, .multicombine = TRUE,
                     .export = c("acsX", "acsY", "alphas", "theFolds"),
                     .packages = "glmnet") %dopar%
  {
    print(alphas[i])
    cv.glmnet(x=acsX, y=acsY, family="binamial", nfolds=5,
              foldid = theFolds, alpha = alphas[i])
  }
# stop timing
after <- Sys.time()
# make sure to stop the cluster when done
stopCluster(cl)
# time difference
# this will depend on speed, memory & number of cores of the machine
after - before
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `cv.glmnet` call. It should be `family="binomial"`; not binamial.

Including `.verbose=TRUE` in your foreach loop will show if you get any errors from your cluster nodes.

Comment: thank you very much, now it worked well! sorry about the typo.

Comment: could I ask you to approve my answer if you found it helpful?